# How do you use a variable in a query?

Tags: php, sql

```
$this->db->query('SELECT Given_Name FROM member WHERE Member_No = $id_no');
echo $this->table->generate($query);
```

I am trying to perform this above scripts with the id_no variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQLi,
It's best to use prepared statements:

```
$q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT Given_Name FROM member WHERE Member_No = ?;");
$q->bind_param("s", $id_no);
$q->execute();

$member = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))["Given_Name"];
```

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: How can you tell OP is using mysqli?

Comment: Oops I didn't read the tags correctly, I swear I read "mysqli" "php" "phomyadmin"